# Parse.com - .get() is returning an [object Object]?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have `Post`s and `Topic`s on Parse. There are ~20 different `Topic`s - each `Post` stores up to 5 of them in an array relationship.

When a `Post` is updated, I need to check the `Topic`s it's assigned to and potentially send out notifications.

So I wrote this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Post", function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var postObject = request.object;
    var postTitle  = postObject.get("title");
    var topics     = postObject.get("topic");
    var topicCount = topics.length;

    console.log("Post with title " + postTitle + " has " + topicCount + " topics: " + topics);

    // code continues to push logic,
    // but already the log above is wrong, so I'll leave that off.
}
```

For example, if I make a post with a title of "Porsche Takes Aim at Tesla" and give it a single topic, the one for "tech", I would expect it to log something like:

```
Post with title Porsche Takes Aim at Tesla has 1 topics: tech
```

But instead when I do this, it logs:

```
Post with title Porsche Takes Aim at Tesla has undefined topics: [object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong? The documentation suggests that when you call `get` with the name of an array field, it should return a JavaScript array. Instead it seems to be returning a blank JavaScript object without any attributes or contents at all.

I just need some way of seeing which topics are attached and iterating through them.

Note that I know this object is being created properly because I can see it in the data browser just fine. Navigating to the `Post` and then clicking on `View Relationship` under `topic` shows me that it's properly connected to the `tech` topic.

Answer (score 2):

First: `[object Object]` doesn't mean that object is empty. Use `JSON.stringify()` to see it's contents.

As I understand topic is an object. In this case you shouldn't expect it to be printed as "tech". I guess you meant some property of this topic, like "name".

There may be also problem with setting the topic. Make sure to always use something like `postObject.set("topic", arrayWithTopicsInside)` because I think that you have set this to topic that is not in an array. You may need to remove that column so it can be added with different type.

I think it should look like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Post", function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var postObject = request.object;
    var postTitle  = postObject.get("title");
    var topics     = postObject.get("topic");

    Parse.Object.fetchAll(topic).then(function(topics) {
        var topicNames = []
        _.each(topics, function(topic) {
            var name = topic.get("name");
            names.push(name);
        });
        console.log("Post with title " + postTitle + " has " + topicNames.count + " topics: " + topicNames);

    }, function(error) {
        concole.log("error fetching objects" + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```